# post process the output information from subprocess.run in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I was trying to print cuda information inside Python

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["nvcc","--version"],capture_output=True)
```

The result is shown as follows

```
CompletedProcess(args=['nvcc', '--version'], returncode=0, stdout=b'nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver\r\nCopyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation\r\nBuilt on Mon_Nov_30_19:15:10_Pacific_Standard_Time_2020\r\nCuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67\r\nBuild cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0\r\n', stderr=b'')
```

Are there any ways to make the above output more readable?

After trying `info = list(subprocess.run(["nvcc","--version"],capture_output=True))`

I got the following error message

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#first store your output in a list like this:

info = list(subprocess.run(...))

#then format your output and print it:

x = '''
command: {0}
statuscode: {1}
output:
{2}
error : 
{3}
'''

print(x.format("".join(info.args), info.returncode, info.stdout, info.sterr))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I got the error message shown in the original post.